# VBA - Running two loops for even and uneven lines

Tags: vba

I'm trying to run "select case" with loops in VBA, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong(every loop work alone, but when I try using them together I'm getting "compile error".

What I'm trying to accomplish is checking if a row and the row following that row (and that row only), has a certain status that is not correct (does not have to be the same status).

thanks

```
Sub du()


      With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i, Status
   Dim x, Status1

    NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To NumRows Step 2

   NumRows1 = cells(Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 3 To NumRows1 Step 2

    Status = cells(i, 8).Value
     Status1 = cells(x, 8).Value

   Select Case Status
        Case "Pl", "In", "Sapt", "Recd"
         Select Case Status1
        Case "Pl", "In", "Sapt", "Recd"
        cells(i, 52).Value = "dp"




   End Select
        End Select
  Next i
 Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the second loop, one loop will do it:

```
Sub du()

Dim i, Status
Dim x, Status1
Dim t As String

t = "Pl, In, Sapt, Recd"
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    NumRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To NumRows
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Status = Cells(i, 8).Value
            Status1 = Cells(i + 1, 8).Value
            If InStr(t, Status) And InStr(t, Status1) Then
                Cells(i, 52).Value = "dp"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```